# API to edit web.xml from Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, web.xml

What is the easiest way to edit web.xml from an Eclipse plugin?
(I'm looking for an API -- as opposed to using a PrintWriter etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is to get hold of the WebApp object. For instance, to add a servlet to web.xml:

```
import org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager;
import org.eclipse.jst.javaee.web.WebApp;

WebApp webApp = (WebApp) ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(project).getModelObject();
Servlet servlet = WebFactory.eINSTANCE.createServlet();
servlet.setServletName("myServlet"); //$NON-NLS-1$
servlet.setServletClass("org.my.class.path"); //$NON-NLS-1$
webApp.getServlets().add(servlet);
```

One can add other tags like servlet-mappings and filters similarly.